# Question shows it was bumped by a user, but no activity is seen?

Tags: support, bump, homepage

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941640/help-understanding-c-optimization) was apparently bumped by [Justin Morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/599168/justin-morgan). It shows this on the front page of SO: `1min ago Justin Morgan`

However, looking at the question, I don't see anything Justin Morgan actually did. Is this a bug?

Comment: Queue up second bug report: links don't look like links when they are above inline code

Comment: Justin added an answer, then deleted it.  This has to be a dupe.

Comment: @Moron - Please add your comment as an answer, since I think the reasoning you have given is the correct answer. Not sure about the dupe tough.

Comment: A few incarnations of this exist, but not quite 'exact' duplicates as each questioned possibly broken behavior at different points in time. Still, not a bug... closing as too localized.

Comment: Flagged for reopening as a [support] question instead because I think it's a useful question (which has been answered successfully), but as @Tim said, it's not a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was bumped because Justin added an answer. You don't see anything because he deleted it.

(I can see a deleted answer from Justin)